# Recursive static content display with Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

G'day,

I've written a piece of software in Python 3.x with PySide which dynamically displays images (as a slideshow) from a network directory. The software works as intended for local machines (i.e. the slideshow is displayed on the machine which is running the software).

I would like to run the software on a centralised server, which then serves each image of the slideshow temporarily on a local network web page. I've managed to serve static content in my code using the Flask library. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
def ServeImage(self, DisplayImage):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/")
    def main():
        return '''<img src='{}' />'''.format(url_for('static', filename=DisplayImage))

    app.run(host='10.2.x.x', port=5000)
```

'DisplayImage' is the output image path from my current code. At present, the above will correctly display the image in the browser at the designated local address. However, I'm unsure how to return to the slideshow component of the software (where the DisplayImage is generated). It appears that once ServeImage() has been called, the code terminates. I believe it's due to the way this example Flask function was put together. What I'm hoping for is detailed in the pseudo-code below:

```
def ServeImage(self, DisplayImage):

    app = Flask(__name__)

    '''<img src='{}' />'''.format(url_for('static', filename=DisplayImage))
    app.run(host='10.2.x.x', port=5000)
    #Timer
    self.ImageNumber += 1
    self.SlideShow()
```

I don't know whether this is possible. As mentioned above, it appears that when app.run() is called, that particular address is served forever, so any code coming after app.run() will never be run. What I'd like is: once the image has been served (i.e. once app.run() has been called), the ImageNumber() variable is changed, and the main SlideShow() function is called, which in turn generates the next DisplayImage to be served on the web page.

Any clarification/suggestions here would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: It's better to have the web page drive the updates. The flask app might be better just serving images. You could have your slides show images named predictably and just request each one in turn e.g image1.jpg, image2.jpg etc. the more robust way would be to have your flask app serve some json with the list of images named explicitly. Then your web page just requests them one after another.

Comment: If you want the flask server to push image updates consider web sockets.

Comment: I'm struggling to envision how that would work. Would accessing the web page cause code to be executed? I'm trying to avoid a client-side implementation if at all possible. I'd rather the server blindly serves content to a web page, as opposed to a web page requesting content from a server.

Comment: if you want to serve a slideshow that changes without a page reload you will need to use client side stuff ... if you just want the next visit to have a different image then use session variables ... if you want the next visitor to get a different image use a database or flat file or some other persistent data

Comment: That was going to be my next question Joran, thanks for clearing that up. It looks like client-side is the logical choice. I've got zero experience with client-side, which is why I was trying to avoid it for the time being. I can't image this is a particularly difficult implementation. Would json be a good choice?

Comment: Json would be a good choice when you are returning data to the client. It's handled naturally by javascript, so there's no need to parse it manually.

Comment: Thanks for that Paul. I've been researching web sockets, as per your previous recommendation. I think a Javascript client-side, receiving socket data from a Python server-side will be a neat way of packaging this. I'm facing a steep learning curve with this particular method, but I've been meaning to learn JS for a long time now!